# Converting the value of a string textbox in java to an integer so the value can be used in multiplication

Tags: java, netbeans, textbox, type-conversion

Hey I am trying to convert string text boxes so i can multiply two variables and the display it in a third text box. My text boxes are txtTotalPre and i am trying to multiply this number by 1 and then display it in txtTotal.

```
   String number = txtSub.getText();
   String.valueOf(number);
   int price = 1;
   txtTotal.setText(number * price);
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, Please make it a habit to search before posting! It is more than likely someone else had the same problems too

Answer (score 1):

try

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(txtSub.getText());
```

instead of

```
String number = txtSub.getText();
String.valueOf(number);
```